# Bash - Find directory containing specific logs file

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a script to quickly analyze some logs and automatically provide advices to solve problems based on errors found.
All works as expected.

However, it's appears that folders structure containing these logs can change (depends on system configuration) and my script not work any more.

I would like to find a way to find the directory containing a specifics files like logs or appinfo.txt file.

Once obtains I could use it as variable and finally solve my problem.

**Here is an example:**

```
AppLogDirectory ='Your_Special_Command_You_Will_HelpMe_To_Find'
grep -i "Error" $AppLogDirectory/esl*.log
```

- Log format is: ESL.randomValue.log
- Files analyzed : appinfo.txt,
  system.txt etc ..

A suggested in comment section, I edit my orginal post with more detail to clarify the context, below an example:

```
Log files (esl.xxx.tt.ss.log ) can be in random directory, like: 
/var/log/ApplicationName/logs/
/opt/ApplicationName/logs/
/var/data/ApplicationName/Extended/logs/
```

Because of random directory, I need to find a solution to print the directory names of the files that match esl*.log patter (without esl filename)

Comment: You mean like `find . -name "esl.*.log"`? This will find the files, not the parent directory.

Comment: The `find` command is probably a good starting point: `find . -type f \( -name 'esl*.log' -o -name appinfo.txt -o -name system.txt \)`. This will find all files you mention (any `esl*.log` file plus the two `.txt` files). And if you add `-exec grep "Error" {} \;` it will even grep them for you.

Comment: Another option consists in using just `grep` with its `--recursive` and `--include` options: `grep --recursive --include 'esl*.log' --include appinfo.txt --include system.txt Error`. Or to install `ack` and use it.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your quick reply and for this good start, output seems to address a aprt of my needs. However, my goal is to find the directory containing these files. To simplify, the command must answer to the following question : In what directory esl*.log files are located

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` and pass the output to `xargs` with `grep`, like so, which runs `grep` on multiple files and prints the output together with the file name where the pattern was found:

```
find /path/to/files /another/path/to/other/files \( -name 'appinfo.txt' -o -name 'system.txt' -o -name 'esl*.log' \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'Error'
```

Or simply use `-exec ... \+`, which gives the same effect, without the need for `xargs`:

```
find /path/to/files /another/path/to/other/files \( -name 'appinfo.txt' -o -name 'system.txt' -o -name 'esl*.log' -exec grep -i 'Error' \+
```

To find the directories which contain the files that contain the desired pattern, use `grep -l` to print file names only (not the lines that match), and pipe the results to `xargs dirname` to print the directory names. If you need the unique dir names, pipe it further to `sort -u`:

```
find /path/to/files /another/path/to/other/files \( -name 'appinfo.txt' -o -name 'system.txt' -o -name 'esl*.log' -exec grep -il 'Error' \+ | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[GNU `find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
[To search for files based on their contents](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Contents)
[`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)

Comment: find has the -exec option: Just `find /path/to/files /another/path/to/other/files \( -name 'appinfo.txt' -o -name 'system.txt' -o -name 'esl*.log' \) -exec grep -Hi error {} \;`

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you! However, the example you give does not print the file names - something that may be useful to many users.

Comment: `grep -H` prints the filename

Comment: ps: If you -exec another tool than grep, which does not print the filename itself, you can use `find ... -exec tool {} \; -print` or even `find ... -exec {} \; -o print`, if you don't care about the exit state of the command to be called, meaning it's not acting as a filter

Comment: GNU `grep` alone can search recursively and only in files which names match patterns: `grep -H --recursive --include 'esl*.log' --include appinfo.txt --include system.txt Error`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet This is right, but as you said, only GNU grep can do this, it's not POSIX and therefore not portable. i.e: If you put this into an answer on SO, 5 mins later someone will come and tell you it's not working on a mac :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you, I modified the answer to include the usage of `find` with `-exec ... \+`, which is simpler.

Comment: @hek2mgl It **is** working on mac. At least with the default 2010 BSD version of `grep` that comes with macOS. But you are right, if we search we should find a grep version that does not support this.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Didn't know it's working with BSD grep. Thanks for this input. I would say if it works by default on Linux and Mac ( ... and BSD ), it's definitely worth to put into answer here. Also, don't get me wrong, as a Linux user I'm using it every day. grep -r is nice, no question. (Older UNIX folks would argue it's doing too much; meaning it violates the concept of simple, chainable tools.. you'll find this discussion on the net :) )

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, however, just to clarify. my goal is find the path where are localted the file (without the filename) - Like /var/opt/application/logs/ (this folder contains esl.xxx-yyyyyy-ssss-iii.log)

Comment: @LEFBE Updated the answer to print the directory names of the files that match the desired pattern. You may want to update your original question to clarify what you are asking. This will help other users (who may not necessarily read the long chain of comments).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution found thanks to you thank you again!**

```
#Ask for extracted tar.gz folder
    read -p "Where did you extract the tar.gz file? r1

#directory path where esl files is located
    logpath=`find $r1 -name "esl*.log" | xargs dirname | sort -u` 

#Search value (here "Error") into all esl*.log 
    grep 'Error' $logpath/esl*.log | awk '{print $8}'
```